# -exec option and license handling for stack on start

Tags: ocean, petrel

When running Petrel with the -exec option you can specify the -licensePackage to pick a license.

How do I set up the -licensePackage when the user has stack on start licensing?
Is any documentation available about how stack on start works?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're correct. Stack-On-Start (SOS) lets the user creates his or her own package(s) with corresponding modules. The names of the packages are then used as argument to the `-licensePackage` option.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of license packages is done in the "License packages..." window (LPW). The LPW displays a list of available packages in the left pane and a list of available modules (for the selected package) in the right pane.

Typically, you start of by copying an existing package. Do this by selecting a package and click the "Create a new package..." icon, which is placed above the package list (with a green 'insert row' symbol).

Now, configure the newly created package by selecting or deselecting appropriate modules according to you necessities. Note that unlicensed modules will be grayed out and cannot be selected.

Save your changes by clicking the "OK" button. Keep in mind the name of the package you are configuring since you invoke a certain package by its name.

For instance:

```
      -licensePackage Foo
```

will start Petrel with the Foo license package and have its corresponding modules to its disposal.